# Change color of java keywords in Eclipse editor

Tags: android, eclipse

How can I change the color of the java keywords
like "package" "public" "class" etc in Eclipse java editor ? I hate the default purple color, Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Eclipse:  Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring > "Keyword 'return'" and "Keywords excluding 'return'"