# Is there a way to prevent the semi-bolding of Java keywords in Eclipse? (example pics inside)

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to switch to a "proper" IDE, but I just can't get past the terrible way it displays the font.

I'm using the Monaco Font in both sublimeText and Eclipse, both with a size of 9, regular.

Sublime looks like this: 
[image]

Whereas Eclipse's rendering of the same font looks like this: 
[image]

It's all semi-bold and smudgy looking! I notice that most of this is only for java keywords like, "public," "class," etc.. non keywords look fine. So, I'm guessing this is editable somewhere in Eclipse's many, many menus.

Does anyone know how to turn off the semi-bolding of keywords?

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Faccessibility%2Ffontsandcolors.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Window menu, choose Preferences. Then type "font" in the search field. You'll see the colors and fonts option that lets you adjust the appearance of several different languages, including Java. I assume you can remove the bold, although I didn't check the details.

The options described on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10592731/4794) may also be relevant.

Comment: Your linked question described it perfectly. I was looking in the wrong place. The bolding information is in a separate java category, rather than the main `fonts and colors` menu. Thanks a bunch!